# Unity particle system play after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, project, collision, particle-system

I made a Project in Unity, a game to be clear. So the player has a Sci-fi car and he tries to avoid obstacles-rocks. 
When the car hits a rock, the Game Manager load the "credits" screen to choose between quit or restart. 
My problem is that I want to make the rock explode when the car goes on it and then the Game Manager will load the "credits" screen.

Some of my code:

For player collision:

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerMovement movement;     
    public static bool y = true;

    public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        // We check if the object we collided with has a tag called "Obstacle".
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {          
            movement.enabled = false;   // Disable the players movement.
            y = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();            
        }
    }
}
```

Game Manager:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

bool gameHasEnded = false;

public float restartDelay = 1f;

public GameObject completeLevelUI;

public void CompleteLevel ()
{
    completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void EndGame ()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
    {
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
        Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
    }
}

void Restart ()
    {
         SceneManager.LoadScene("Credits");
         //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
     }
}
```

The endTrigger:

```
public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameManager gameManager;

    void OnTriggerEnter ()
    {
        gameManager.CompleteLevel();
    }
}
```

LevelComplete:

```
public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LoadNextLevel ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); 
    }
}
```

Menu:

```
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

    public void StartGame ()
    {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);  
    }
}
```

I have written other scripts. If you want anything let me know. Thanks guys.

Comment: Add an empty gameObject with the particle effects you want. Add this empty gameObject to rocks in your scene. Make sure you have disabled them first. When collision happens, enable them. After that load your credits scene. You can use coroutine for that.

Comment: How I make them active when the collision happens?

Comment: You can start by searching in google. "How to enable gameobject unity" like so. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/activating-gameobjects) is one from Unity.

Comment: i cant find anything. I had try too much differnet things and nothing....

Comment: Can you enable/disable any gameobject through code without any pre-condition ?

Comment: I dont know!! If I put the explosion on my player and after a collision it blows up? Is that possible? I tried this but again explodes in the start of the game not after the collision.

Answer (score 1):

Add a particle system to your rocks. Uncheck "looping" and "play on awake". Then you can play by adding the line below.

```
public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    // We check if the object we collided with has a tag called "Obstacle".
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {          
        movement.enabled = false;   // Disable the players movement.
        y = false;
        collisionInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play(); // play the explosion
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I upload an image to see how I put it on. moreover, the gamescene Manager doesn't load the next scene after i put the code you wrote.

Comment: You need to modify the line I added to correctly navigate to and obtain the particlesystem. Additionally make sure that "Play on Awake" is not checked.

Comment: modify how? i'm a newbie, sorry for that. furthermore, the Play on Awake is unchecked to both of TrailsBlack & TrailsWhite ParticleSystems.

Comment: that depends on where your particle system gameobject is in relation to the collider. For example, if `Rocks` has the collider and `Explosion` has your particle system you could do: collisionInfo.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();

Comment: yeah, right this is it, the rocks has the collider and the explosion has the particle systems. I tried this but I get an error: 'ParticleSystem' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: paste the line of code that is giving you the error.

Comment: collisionInfo.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<​ParticleSystem>().Pl‌​ay();

Comment: type the line into your script instead of copying and pasting from here. I think it is identifying some components incorrectly...?

Comment: yeah, I tried this and in vs I didnt get any error. But again its not working, such as the obstacle.... I mean that now the car doesn't stop in front of the rock as it did, and it goes inside when the explosion is somewhere near, but if I take the Explosion GameObject not as children of the obstacle and move somewhere further, the obstacle works properly and the "explosion" explodes in the start!

Comment: can I ,with another way, put the "explosion" on the car instead of the rock?

Comment: yes, you could do something similar to play a particle system on the car instead. just attach a particle system to the car, find and get that component instead, and play it.

Comment: I already did that, but the result is that the car explodes in the start of the game, not when it hits obstacles.

Comment: That either means the car is colliding with an object immediately or you have the particle system set to play on awake.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your approach.  As I understand you already have an endTrigger [With a Collider Trigger] that ends the game if the player goes inside. So uncheck the trigger in the player collider and instead  **add that trigger to the rocks collider**, so when the player crashes it will:

- Activate the Particle System
- Makes the rock invisible
- End the Game

You can add this script to your rock and see how it works

```
public class RockTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameManager gameManager;
    ParticleSystem myParticleSystem;

    void Awake()
    {
        myParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        myParticleSystem.Play();
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>.enabled = false;
        gameManager.GetComponent<GameManager>().EndGame();

    }
}
```

*Note about the OnTriggerEnter*: In case you only have the player moving in the scene this is fine like this (I use the same pattern you used in EndGame),
but in case there were other GameObject with a RigidBody moving in the
scene you should check if `other` is indeed the player. Usually tagging the player and the checking `if(other.tag == "Player")`